# Some font awesome icons aren't showing

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I use fontawesome to show icons in my project

For example I use these tags in some place

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="fas fa-map"></i>
<i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i>
```

The first one is being shown but the second one isn't.
Consider that both of icons are free icons

Comment: I created a snippet. Neither seems to be shown

Comment: there is no issue with your code, icons are showing fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using version 5's syntax but linking to version 4 FA's css.

```
fa or fas = Font Awesome Solid
far = Font Awesome Regular
fal = Font Awesome Light
fab = Font Awesome Brands


<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>  <!-- version 4's syntax -->

<i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i> <!-- version 5's syntax -->
<i class="far fa-camera-retro"></i> <!-- example: regular style of camera-retro -->
<i class="fal fa-camera-retro"></i> <!-- example: light style of camera-retro -->
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fas fa-map"></i>
<i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i>
```

Comment: i am using same version but problem still exist inside my project although it's working in code snippet